# PHP preg_match_all $matches output contains 3 rows

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Here is my test code:

```
$test = '@12345 abc @12 @abd engng@geneng';
preg_match_all('/(^|\s)@([^@ ]+)/', $test, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

And the output `$matches`:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => @12345 [1] => @12 [2] => @abd ) [1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 12345 [1] => 12 [2] => abd ) )
```

My question is why does it have an empty row?

```
[1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

If I get ride of `(^|\s)` in the `regex`, the second row will disappear. However I would not able to prevent matching `@geneng`.

Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regular expression is that it matches `@` even when it is preceded by whitespace. Because `\s` will match the whitespace, it will be captured into `$matches` array. You can solve this problem by using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In this case, it can be solved with a positive lookbehind:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@([^@ ]+)/', $test, $matches);
```

This will match the part after `@` *only* if it is preceded by a space or beginning-of-the line anchor. It's important to note that lookarounds do not actually consume characters. They just assert that the given regular expression is either followed or preceded by something.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/139359)

Comment: Thanks mate! You were so quick, I even have to wait 2 minutes to accept your answer!

Comment: Just curious why not use `@\S+(?= )` ?

Comment: @hwnd: That wouldn't match `@foo` if it occurs at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the memory capture to test `(^|\s)`:

```
preg_match_all('/(^|\s)@([^@ ]+)/', $test, $matches);
                 ^^^^^^
```

It's captured as memory location #1, so to avoid that you can simply use non-capturing parentheses:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)@([^@ ]+)/', $test, $matches);
                  ^^
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but I only can upvote you, because Amal was slight faster than you. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all uses by default the PREG_PATTERN_ORDER flag. This means that you will obtain:

```
$matches[0] -> all substrings that matches the whole pattern
$matches[1] -> all capture groups 1
$matches[2] -> all capture groups 2
etc.
```

You can change this behavior using the PREG_SET_ORDER flag:

```
$matches[0] -> array with the whole pattern and the capture groups for the first result
$matches[1] -> same for the second result
$matches[2] -> etc.
```

In your code you (PREG_PATTERN_ORDER by default) you obtain $matches[1] with only empty or blank items because it is the content of capture group 1 `(^|\s)`

Comment: @AmalMurali: I think like that: `(?:^|\s)@\K[^@\s]+` . or including the arobase.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 set of parentheses that's why you get an empty row. PHP thinks, you want 2 set of matching in the string. Removing one of them will remove one array.

FYI: In this case, you can not use [^|\s] instead  of (^|\s). Cause PHP will think, you want to exclude the white space.